# Create sub-headings in a react dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu using the react component . The code is below:

```
<Select
    style={{ width: 300 }}
    options={people}
    onChange={this.choosePerson}
    placeholder="Select person">
</Select>
```

The person object is as follows:

```
const people = [];
people.push({
  label: 'John'
  value: 'John'
});
people.push({
  label: 'Mary'
  value: 'Mary'
});
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to have sub-headings within this drop down menu in order to group the people (e.g. Men, Women). I have found it possible when using plain javascript but I can't seem to find how to do it with the set up I currently have.

Comment: Will you be able to provide the code how you structure your `Select` component? A codesandbox maybe?

Comment: @bertdida sorry I don't fully understand, the select component wasn't created by me it comes with React

Comment: Ohh you mean from a library. What library are you using for your `Select` component?

Comment: Isn't react.js the library?

Comment: I've imported Select from ant design, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep. I think you're looking for something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/7xr11. Check the docs on Ant Design https://ant.design/components/select/.

Comment: I am looking for something like that yes! Although I would like to do it without having to move my values to the render function and having to put them all in between tags. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve it like this:

```
<Select defaultValue="Select Person" onChange={this.selectPerson} style={{ width: 300 }}>
    <OptGroup label="Man">
    {
      this.state.men.map(function(man) {
          return (<Option key = {man.value}> {man.label}</Option>);
      })
    }
    </OptGroup>
    <OptGroup label="Women">
       {
        this.state.women.map(function(woman) {
            return (<Option key = {woman.value}> {woman.label}</Option>);
         })
    }
    </OptGroup>
</Select>
```